# How to use chroot in a Makefile?

Tags: linux, makefile, debian, splash-screen, chroot

I am building my own Debian-based Linux with own kernel and software. One of the last steps of the make-process has to be done in a chrooted environment:

- Install the custom kernel using dpkg
- Create symbolic links to the kernel and initrd.img
- Execute ldconfig
- Set my custom theme for the splash screen using plymouth
- Update the initrd.img

While the installation of the kernel succeeds and the symbolic links are acutally created, all other commands do not seem to work. If I boot into the system the splash screen is set to the default and the initrd.img cannot find the HDD nor the kernel. So the updating of the initrd.img inside the dpkg-installation process seems to fail somehow. The plymouth script to set the theme does not work either.

To fix this, I manually chroot into the system and do the following:

- Set my custom theme for the splash screen using plymouth
- Execute ldconfig
- Update the initrd.img

This works perfectly fine. Next time I boot the system, my splash screen is shown and everything starts properly.

Here is my approach to get this done in my Makefile:

```
cp $(INTEGRATION_KERNEL_IMAGE) $(ROOTFS)/tmp/kernel.deb
cd $(ROOTFS); /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mount -t proc proc proc/; /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mount -t sysfs sys sys/; /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mount -o bind /dev dev/
/usr/sbin/chroot --userspec=0:0 $(ROOTFS) /usr/bin/env -i PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/tools/bin HOME=/root bash -c "/usr/bin/dpkg --force-not-root -i /tmp/kernel.deb"
/usr/sbin/chroot --userspec=0:0 $(ROOTFS) /usr/bin/env -i PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/tools/bin HOME=/root bash -c "/bin/ln -nsf vmlinuz-3.2.54-rt75custom /boot/vmlinuz"
/usr/sbin/chroot --userspec=0:0 $(ROOTFS) /usr/bin/env -i PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/tools/bin HOME=/root bash -c "/bin/ln -nsf initrd.img-3.2.54-rt75custom /boot/initrd.img"
/usr/sbin/chroot --userspec=0:0 $(ROOTFS) /usr/bin/env -i PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/tools/bin HOME=/root bash -c "/sbin/ldconfig"
/usr/sbin/chroot --userspec=0:0 $(ROOTFS) /usr/bin/env -i PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/tools/bin HOME=/root bash -c "/bin/bash /usr/sbin/plymouth-set-default-theme my_theme"
/usr/sbin/chroot --userspec=0:0 $(ROOTFS) /usr/bin/env -i PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/tools/bin HOME=/root bash -c "/bin/bash /usr/sbin/update-initramfs -u"
/usr/bin/sudo /bin/umount $(ROOTFS)/proc; /usr/bin/sudo /bin/umount $(ROOTFS)/sys; /usr/bin/sudo /bin/umount $(ROOTFS)/dev
```

The output of make does not provide any errors on this topic. Well, it possibly cannot do this because make does not know what is going on inside the chrooted environment. But how can I find out what is going wrong?

A possible workaround would be to put everything I mentioned above in a shell script and execute this in the chrooted environment. But I would prefer to do everything in the Makefile and  I do not know if the workaround really works. I have not verified this yet.

Answer (score 0):

- Have you tried saving command output in the chroot environment and extracting it later? For example:

  ```
  /usr/sbin/chroot [...] bash -c "/usr/bin/dpkg [...] >> /root/chroot.log"
  ```

  or

  ```
  /usr/sbin/chroot [...] bash -c "/usr/bin/dpkg [...] | tee -a /root/chroot.log"
  ```

  followed by

  ```
  cp $(ROOTFS)/root/chroot.log .
  ```
- In the long run I would suggest to avoid code duplication and Makefile clutter, either by passing everything in a single `chroot` command or by copying over a script.
- You should be able to get rid of most or all of the `bash -c` and `/bin/bash` invocations. That should simplify things even more.

Comment: Okay, I added the logging to all of my chroot commands but no error is reported. I think I should try the script approach.